# Bringing a constant out of double integral (polar coordinates)

Tags: integration

Question is: Using polar coordinates, evaluate the integral $\iint\sin(x^2+y^2)dA$ where R is the region $1\le x^2+y^2\le81$

My work for the inside integral, using bounds 1 to 9, was a constant:
 
$$\int_1^9\sin(r^2)rdr=-\frac{1}{2}\left(\cos81-\cos1\right)$$

Does this mean I can conclude my answer is this constant? In other words, can I bring it out of the integral with respect to theta from 0 to 2$\pi$? I am guessing not because my answer was not correct. If not, could someone explain why?

Comment: Try using MathJax to make your question more readable.

Comment: Yes you can bring it out. The answer should be correct. What number are you getting for your answer?

Comment: @JohnDoe The answer is that constant (my answer) times 2pi.

Comment: That's the same answer I get.  What is the "correct" answer.

Comment: I get $-0.74...$. What **number** are you getting? Do you have an actual number? That would help us figure out what your issue is

Comment: Sorry for the unclarity. I am getting -0.118... and the correct answer is −0.742...

Comment: I don't get it.  After multiplying your answer above by $2\pi$ I get $-.742...$  What was your constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ignored the angular part of the integral: $$\int\int_R\sin(x^2+y^2)\,dx\,dy=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_1^9r\sin(r^2)\,dr\,d\theta\\=\left(\int_0^{2\pi}\,d\theta\right)\left(\int_1^9r\sin(r^2)\,dr\right)=2\pi\times(-0.118\dots)=-0.74\dots$$

Comment: Good eye.  I couldn't figure out *what* was going on.

Comment: I am still not entirely sure how you get 2pi from the first integral. Are you taking an integral of 1?

Comment: @saulspatz haha yes - _now_ that comment makes sense: "The answer is that constant (my answer) times 2pi"

Comment: @h.jb yes, we are $$\int_0^{2\pi}\,d\theta=\int_0^{2\pi}1\,d\theta=[\theta]_0^{2\pi}=2\pi$$Does that make sense now? We can split the integral in this way because there are no terms with $\theta$ in the original integral.